# How can I display all the Types and Values in my XML file

Tags: c#, xml, element, display

I have an XML file,all of it with same elements :`<field >   </field>`

Every field has type "XXX" ,  and also : `<value>AAA</value>`

I want to display all the types and values in console mode

Examples :

```
type  : MrzType        type:  DocumentType          ....
Value : 2line          Value: P
```

I have this code:

```
XmlDocument Xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
Xmldoc.Load(@"C:\image.xml");

foreach (XmlElement element in Xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("field"))
{
     if (element.HasAttribute("type"))
     {
           Console.WriteLine("type : " + element.GetAttribute("type"));
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Value : " + element.InnerText);
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

But i have just the result:

```
type : MrzType Value : 2line
```

I want to display all types and their values?

This is my file XML ,image.xml:

```
<document>
<field type="MrzType">
<value>2line</value>
</field>
<field type="DocumentNumber">
<value>R420604</value>
</field>
<field type="DocumentType">
<value>P</value>
</field>
<field type="DocumentSubtype">
<value>&lt;</value>
</field>
<field type="IssuingCountry">
<value>TUN</value>
</field>
<field type="LastName">
<value>THABET</value>
</field>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cut the `Console.ReadLine();`line and paste it after }

Answer (score 0):

You must delete `Console.ReadLine();` statment.

The loop stop after one itteration. When do this result is:

[image]

Comment: Merci bien,
il affiche le resultat ..mais il disparut direct ..le Console.ReadLine(); s'est obligatoire ..
mais just il faut le met après le bloc foreach 
Comme ça ,il marche bien
Je vous remercie